# Common interface method implementation in java

Tags: java, interface, java-8, static-methods

I have 2 classes that implements a particular interface.
I would like to implement a method that would be shared by the 2 classes.
Can I add that method implementation to the interface class and then make a call to that method from the 2 classes?

For eg:

```
public interface DM 
{
    public static void doSomething() { 
        System.out.println("Hello World");}
    }

    public class A implements DM
    {
        doSomething();
    }

    public class B implements DM
    {
        doSomething();
    }
}
```

Is this feasible?
What is the proper way to do this?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes, if you are using Java 8, you can create a `default` implementation, like this:

```
public interface DM
{
    default void doSomething() { System.out.println("Hello World");}
}
```

or, if it should be static:

```
public interface DM
{
    static void doSomething() { System.out.println("Hello World");}
}
```

For more information, see [Oracle's documentation on the feature](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/IandI/defaultmethods.html)

Another strategy you could use, if you are able to make more widespread changes to your code, would be to use an `abstract class` instead of an interface, and have your implementing classes `extend` that class instead. Any methods in your interface that you do not want to write defaults for should be marked as `abstract`.

```
public abstract class DM
{
    public void doSomething() { System.out.println("Hello World");}
    public abstract void doSomethingElse();
}

public class A extends DM
{
  doSomething();
}
```

You could also combine the approaches if you want to use interfaces but can't/won't use defaults:

```
public abstract class DMImpl impelements DM
{
    @Override        
    public void doSomething() { System.out.println("Hello World");}
}

public class A extends DM
{
  doSomething();
}
```

Comment: A more thorough pattern is start with the interface `public interface DM` - create an abstract base class with common/shared/default implementations `public abstract class AbstractBaseDM implements DM` then extend that `public class A extends AbstractBaseDM` and `public class B extends AbstractBaseDM` (however with Java 8 I'll be using _default_ for many of these cases)

Answer (score 3):

You can create a `default` method with Java 8. It has some limitations but good for some commonly shared functionality.

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/IandI/defaultmethods.html

```
interface DM {

    default public void doSomething() {
      System.out.println("Hi");
    }

}
```

Comment: Will work - although note that default methods for interfaces is actually meant to ensure that all implementing classes do not break when a new method is added to an interface. If you really need a common method for two or more classes - consider an abstract class or Composition.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, `interface` is *not a class*. Next, yes, with java 8's [*default methods*](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/IandI/defaultmethods.html), you can add method definitions to *interfaces*,

Answer (score 0):

you can try this

```
interface DM 
{
    public void doSomething();
}

class A implements DM
    {
        public void doSomething()
        {
            System.out.println("Hello World");
        }
    }

class B implements DM
    {
        public void doSomething()
        {
            System.out.println("Hello World");
        }
    }
class Test111
{
    public static void main(String args[])
    {
        System.out.println("Hello");
    }
}
```